# My Cypress test fails on DevExtreme date elements

Tags: angular, date, field, cypress, devextreme

I am writing e2e tests for web application using Cypress test framework. The elements are created using DevExtreme for Angular.

I have a problem with date fields. I must always access these elements using their indexes, which I want to avoid for easier testing. "Name" properties are defined on these fields, but Cypress can't find date elements by name. When I pass "name" property, my test fails.

Html code:

```
<div fxFlex="15" style="margin-right: 2%">
   <dx-date-box width="95%" type="date" displayFormat="{{config.DateFormatDX}}"
       [disabled]="edit" placeholder="{{'DATE' | translate }}"
       name="data.admissionDate" pickerType="calendar" [(ngModel)]="data.admissionDate"
       dateSerializationFormat="dd.MM.yyyy">
   </dx-date-box>
</div>

<div fxFlex="15" style="margin-right: 2%">
   <mat-form-field fxFlex="100">
       <input matInput fxFlex="100" [disabled]="edit" name="data.requestStatusCode"
          placeholder="{{'REQ_STATUS_CODE' | translate}}"
          [(ngModel)]="data.requestStatusCode">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

The test:

it('should enter the date', function() {

//problem      
        cy 
            .get('input[name="data.admissionDate"]')
            .wait(3000)
            .type(this.admin.date)
            .should("have.value", this.admin.date)
            .wait(3000);
})

it('should enter the status code', function() {

//OK
        cy 
            .get('input[name="data.requestStatusCode"]')
            .wait(3000)
            .type(this.admin.statusCode)
            .should("have.value", this.admin.statusCode)
            .wait(3000);
 })
```

Does anyone have any recommendation or advice how to access the DevExtreme date element? I haven't any problem with other kind of elements. For example, Cypress can find status code element and write something in this field.

Comment: Why have you got `.wait()` in your code - that shouldn't be necessary. is dev-xtreme rewriting the elements, which is causing you a timing issue?

Comment: I put .wait() because Cypress sometimes does some actions too quickly. This sometimes causes failure, though it shouldn't. I put .wait() to slow down these test steps and see more clearly what's going on. When I want to publish the tests in Jenkins, I can delete .wait() method, and it works fine. This is the problem only locally, on my computer.

Comment: My main problem is that I must use indexes of elements for accessing dates. I want to avoid this. I can add new date fields, but it will change the indexes. I tried to use name properties on date elements, but it doesn't work. It works on the other kinds of elements, such as text boxes.